# The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files Error on Eclipse Mars Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

please help me. I have a ***problem.***
I am getting the following error:

> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

This is coming up on my package declaration. I am developing an android app, I got this project off the internet... I tried restarting, changing build path, etc. Please help me!!!

***BTW I have no experience with StackExchange... If I'm doing something wrong, please let me know so I can improve. Thanks!***

Comment: Post more of the error stacktrace and the code you are trying to compile that throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that every entry in the project's `Java Build Path` is valid, especially the one for the JRE. You can open the **Properties** dialog using the project's context menu, or the **Project** menu in the menu bar, and use the **Build Path** property page to make changes.